# Ruby background service

Tags: ruby, service, background, daemon, tcpclient

I have a TCPclient written on Ruby. I want to use it in background. Currently it has a loop:

```
loop do
end
```

So i can run a client, and it works forever.

Is there a way to run in as a service, and write a pid to file, then i'll able to kill that process by pid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [daemons gem](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) is made just for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unix system for that :

```
ruby myfile.rb && echo $! > my_file.pid
```